# iOS Video Preview in DetailViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, video, uiimageview

I need an advise regarding to video preview in DetailViewController. I have a tableView based app. I will have some content in my tableView and I want users to tap on the cell and go to the DetailViewController. So far, I was able to get users do this. I have the following storyboard at the moment. But it contains UIImageView in it.

IMAGE: http://cl.ly/image/0c3V121X0T0M

As you can see, I have thumbnailView and some label containing information and again UIImageView in detailViewController. My aim is to show a video on the DetailViewController instead of a UIImageView and some info related to that video. It would be better for me fetch the videos, so I don't need to push new updates every single time I make changes on the videos.

Do you happen to have an answer or any sources that can help me out with this? I have had a look at the resources available but couldn't come up with solid solution so far.

Please let me know if I should provide more regarding to my question.

Comment: please specify solutions you have already tried and did not work

Comment: tried the following solution: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController but couldn't combine video and thumbnailView.

Comment: So you have managed to play video in `DetailViewController` and are only having trouble with thumbnail in `tableView`?

Comment: Not actually. I m able to get the thumbnailView display both on the tableView and detailViewController but not the video. If you have time, you can have a look at the app: http://cl.ly/0O2G3b0p0P1e

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at AVFoundation and AVPlayer. 
[Download Sample from here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)